# Check BCC after the email is sent

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-client, bcc

How is it possible to check the address insert in BCC list after the email is sent?

I use outlook, but I not sure on other email-client (thunderbird/google web mail...)

Comment: Your question is unclear - are you really asking about 'every' mail client or just Outlook (and what version of Outlook)

Comment: Opening the email is it possible to view all details, but from the preview I am not able to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your question is how to see the BCC list after an email is sent in Outlook?

Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 shows it when you "pop" the email (when you expand it).

So, in the sent items, double click on the sent email to open it in it's own window and you will see the full To, CC and (if used) BCC details

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Outlook

Browse ... `Sent Items`

Select Advanced Tab in dialog

Press Field; Select BCC in Address fields;

Set Bcc contain `@` Value; And press `Find Now`

[image]

Create email. Select Option-> Show BCC

[image]

Comment: I was asking after the email was sent

Comment: @Ale Update thx to comment.

Comment: How does this show the BCC **AFTER** the email was sent?

Comment: @Dave see Pic1 and comment to pic. 1